# Random shutdowns and restarts

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, freeze, shutdown

I could use some fresh thoughts regarding my shutdown issue. So, about 2 weeks ago my pc started to occasionally restart while playing games. Sometimes it happens after 4-10 minutes but occasionally it worked without any trouble for hours, seems quite random.
 My first thought was CPU overheating so I checked with coretemp, all cores were around 50-65C during gameplay (highest measured was 72C) which seems normal. The fact that the shutdown happened while I was just logged in on the desktop seems to deny this theory too.
 Second thought was PSU faliure, swapped with a nother one I found at home, no luck.
 Third thought was broken RAM. Ran Memtest86 first time it shut down after 10 minutes without any sign of errors, so I started it again ran for 2,5 hours, 2passes no errors. Coinsidence maybe?
 Few more things I tried: Reinstall windows, Downgrade back to award bios (I updated to the latest beta UEFI some time ago never had issues with it before) Now after all this my bet would be Motherboard failure (just a guess)

Pc setup:
Gigabyte GA Z68XP-UD4 (rev1.3, bios F6), i7 2600k (non overcocked), 2x Corsair Vengence 4Gb (set to 1600Mhz in bios since day 1), Nvidia GeForce GTX570( non overclocked), 700W Chieftec PSU.

I'd appriciate any comments and advices, I really wish this pc to return to it's reliable self...

Comment: Based on the generic symptoms, I'd always say over-heat or under-power. Graphics would be prime candidate for both, rather than CPU/mobo.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll run GPU Z and ungine heaven to see if i can get it to crash.

Comment: Hmm, a few comments gone missing, anyway. I ran a few tests on the GPU(Unigine Heaven, FurMark) no crashes encountered, the temperatures were around 66-68C which as far as I can tell seems fine, not sure about these voltages though.(Test Results: https://goo.gl/Wi4iCm ) People pointed out that maybe the PSU is not giving enough power so I made a quick calculation, according to that 700Ws should be more than enough. There is a really similar config in the house runing with only a 500W PSU without any trouble too.

Comment: So I got new sympoms here. I've taken the GPU out to see whether it starts running smooth or not. I was watching a movie when suddenly the screen started flashing first it was around 1-4/min now it's doing it constantly. Any ideas what could cause something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it's been a while, unfortunately last month I didn't really have time to deal with this finals and all. But now to sum it, the issue was caused by my onboard vga chip. I replaced my mobo a few weeks ago and (fingers crossed) my Pc has worked like a charm ever since. Thanks for all the helpfull ideas guys!